# GitLab CI: No such file or directory: 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv'

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, verbose

I want to run git with the verbose attribute. So I want to set the variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`.

```
 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"
 git clone .....
```

But I get this error message:

```
 No such file or directory: 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv'
```

How could I solve this.  It tried to define the varibale before at the `.gitlab-ci.yml`-file:

```
variables:
  GIT_SSH_COMMAND: ssh -v

before_script:
  - export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"
```

But this doesn't help.

Comment: You should probably do it the way the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) says you should define environment variables.

Comment: @fredrik, also, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you remove the `before_script` when you tried?

Comment: @fredrik Yes, I removed the ``before_script`` part.

Comment: I I remove also the line ``GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"``, it works. But if I want to echo the variable, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try: [GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-fetch-extra-flags)?

Answer (score 0):

I see that variable used directly in the [`script` step of a `gitlab-ci.yml`](https://github.com/XiaoMi/mace/blob/63feaf5055bab6a081d36edfab8f963a624899aa/.gitlab-ci.yml#L123-L127)

```yml
  script:
    - pwd
    - rm -rf mace-models
    - rm -rf generic-mobile-devices
    - GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git clone git@github.com:XiaoMi/mace-models.git
```